# Unable to load DLL 'libuv': The specified module could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

When I open new project of type  `asp.net` mvc .net core  web application and I try to run it, chrome is opend but nothing is showing.

When I put `try catch` on the code in (progran.cs), I get error :-

> Count = error CS0103: The name 'InnerExceptionCount' does not exist in
>   the current context    One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load
>   DLL 'libuv': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8007007E))